# how to have a half star review

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a star review mechanism. Now my question is how do I capture a half star? This is what I am doing to add one star and change the bar showing how many stars on each category. This is working great. Thanks to Barmar for fixing the bug last night. But the half star is really troubling me. The jquery looks like this

```
$('.star').click(function () {
        var num = parseInt($('.likes').eq($(this).index('.star')).text());
        $('.likes').eq($(this).index('.star')).text(num + 1);

        $(this).addClass('active').off('click');
        $(this).prevAll().addClass('active').off('click');
        checkNumber(num+1);

    });
```

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/VU3LP/54/

when I am doing this

```
$('.likes').eq($(this).index('.star')).text(num + .5);
```

I am loosing the index

Comment: Why half stars? Rating is just an opinion, and it's usually not that detailed. Let them choose whole stars only, and use half stars to be more accurate when showing avarages. If you want your users to pick values in more detail, just add more stars.

Comment: @trol--i agree with on that but unfortunately that is the brief.

Comment: What exactly is the problem in using half stars? The accuracy of hovering? Adding a half-star image? Be more precise in **what your technical question is.**

Comment: @deceze--I just cant figure out how to approach it.

Comment: I'd say if you need half stars, just make 10 `.star` divs, each with half a star. Then just put sets of 2 together so they look like a full star still. -- It'd be much quicker than trying to determine if the user clicked on the left or right half of a div - just make 2 divs.

Comment: @ Douglas--yes i tried that. The problem is when I am making ten stars it is not indexing the bar graph components correctly. You should visit the fiddle to see what I mean. Right now it has 5 but feel free to make a copy of another 5 to test it

Answer (score 1):

I made quite a few changes here, but basically I made 10 half stars to make 5 levels of stars. When the user clicks on a half, the corresponding star level total increases by either 0.5 or 1.0 (depending on which half of the star was clicked).

I removed the click event similar to how you had it, but a better method would be to allow users to click a second time, then undo the math from the first click. You'll also note some general code cleanup, etc.

Here's the shortened, relevant HTML

```
<div id="stars">
    <div class="star leftHalf"></div>
    <div class="star rightHalf"></div>
[ ... ]

<div class="barHolder">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1 star</td>
            <td class="bar"></td>
            <td class="likes">20</td>
        </tr>
        [ ... ]
```

CSS

```
.star {
    height:20px;
    width:10px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.star.leftHalf{
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

the full JavaScript / jQuery

```
var baractive = $('<div class="barActive"></div');
baractive.appendTo('.bar');

function checkNumber() {
    $(".likes").each(function () {
        var valueCurrent = parseFloat($(this).text()),
            barActive = $(this).prev(".bar").children(".barActive");

        if (isNaN(valueCurrent) || valueCurrent <= 20) {
            barActive.css('width', 30);
        } else if (valueCurrent <= 60) {
            barActive.css('width', 80);
        }else if (valueCurrent <= 70) {
            barActive.css('width',120);
        }
    });
}
checkNumber();

$('.star').click(function () {
    var starIndex = $("#stars div").index( $(this) ), // current half clicked; 0-9
        starLevel = Math.ceil( ( starIndex+1 )/2 )-1, // current star clicked; 0-4
        valCur = parseFloat( $('.likes').eq(starLevel).text() ), // current likes value
        isHalfStar = starIndex % 2 ? false : true, // is this a half click (left side)?
        valNew = valCur + (isHalfStar ? 0.5 : 1.0); // new likes value

    $('.likes').eq(starLevel).text(valNew);

    $(".star").removeClass("active").off("click");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).prevAll().addClass('active');
    checkNumber();

});
```

And the working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/VU3LP/64/

Comment: +1 for sticking with the problem, offering solution and posting working example. Thank you sir.